# No view found for id when using Fragments

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, fragmentmanager

I've done everything I can find to fix my problem, it's the same as many others with the fragmentmanager that can't find a view.

Tried everything I have found online and could think about.

Heres my MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        MenuFragment menuFragment = new MenuFragment();
        FragmentManager fmStart = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fmTrans = fmStart.beginTransaction();
        fmTrans.add(R.id.fragmentContainerID, menuFragment);
        fmTrans.commitAllowingStateLoss();


    }

    public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, boolean addToBackStack, String tag) {
        FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction ft = manager.beginTransaction();

        if (addToBackStack) {
            ft.addToBackStack(tag);
        }
        ft.replace(R.id.fragmentContainerID, fragment, tag);
        ft.commitAllowingStateLoss();
    }
}
```

The error I get is the same as many others:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f080073 (se.iteda.hangman:id/fragmentContainerID) for fragment MenuFragment{d8a58aa (60d879ee-e84c-425e-a1a1-8e9be9c3b3a8) id=0x7f080073}
```

What I want to do is load a fragment at the start (MenuFragment) and in that fragment, I have 2 buttons that change fragments.

Comment: The whole project can be found at https://github.com/RiftApps/HangStickMan

Comment: Remove this "((MainActivity)getActivity()).addFragment(menuFragment, true, "Menu");" You are creating a new fragment inside the fragment itself. This is wrong.

Comment: Okay, i removed that but the problem is before that fragment even loads so still a crash on app start with the same error

Comment: So I guess the crash is not in the fragment but in the activity that is loading it. Share the activity code

Comment: If you are still here, please consider using androidx.navigation. It saves time and is easy.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok. I opened your project in Github.

Error is here:

MainActivity.java

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ....
    fmTrans.add(R.id.fragmentContainerID, menuFragment);
    ....
}
```

You are adding the fragment into `fragmentContainerID`. However, that view was not added to the `Activity` (leading to the view not found error).

So, in order to fix, I think you just need to apply the layout to the main activity. Something like:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Add this after super.onCreate()
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    .....
}
```

**EDIT**

And as I said in one of my comments, I think you don't need the code below at MenuFragment.java. I think you can remove it.

```
MenuFragment menuFragment = new MenuFragment();
((MainActivity)getActivity()).addFragment(menuFragment, true, "Menu");
```

Comment: Thank you so much, i added the name to the fragment in xml and added setcontentview and that did the trick!!